# Why do we call Java open source, when development or contributions are not decentralized

Tags: java, open-source

Open source software should be developed by different contributors in decentralized fashion. I understand that Open JDK is reference implementation of Java which is open source and it allows contributions towards security and bug fixing. I believe Oracle makes most of the contributions to Open JDK. Does Java qualifies as Open source ?

Comment: Where did you get that definition of open source? You are talking about development methodology, as far as I can see. How is that related to the term open source?

Comment: You may be describing someone's Free Software ideology, sometimes called Open Source (capitalized), but decentralization is not a requirement of what the words "open source" literally mean.

Comment: This is based on my understanding. I am not citing anybody's ideology. Please correct me in my assumptions.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Decentralization is not a central tenet of either Free Software or Open Source (capitalized), and by the way, Free Software != Open Source ([this is a big deal for Free Software advocates](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/open-source-misses-the-point.en.html), and not a minor nitpick).

Comment: I'm afraid this Q is getting downvotes because the OP is wrong abut something. That's why I upvoted it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Why do we call Java open source, when development or contributions are not decentralized?

The definition of "Open Source" provided by the Open Source Initiative makes no mention of accepting contributions, or how software should be developed.

You can read it here:

- The OSI's ["The Open Source Definition"](https://opensource.org/osd) page or the [annotated version](https://opensource.org/osd-annotated).
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Open_Source_Definition) (with some history and commentary).

The term "open source" has no fixed definition.  It means different things to different people.

The other point to make is that the word "Java" means lots of things:

- It is a programming language
- It is a specification of that programming language
- It is an implementation of that language (compilers, core JVM, etc)
- It is an implementation of a language *plus* a large "standard library"
- It is a family of implementations of language + libraries (SE, ME ... EE)
- There is OpenJDK Java versus Oracle Java ... which have *different* licenses.
- There are multiple vendor Java implementations based on the Oracle / Sun code base.
- There are others, like GNU Classpath Java, [Apache Harmony Java](https://harmony.apache.org/) (historical) Android Java, various 3rd-party Java compilers (Jikes, the Eclipse compiler, etc)
- etcetera

So, when you say "we call Java open source", that is an over-generalization ... and in many cases wrong.

---

> Does (OpenJDK) Java qualify as Open Source ?

Yes.  According to the definition linked above.

According to your *personal* definition of open source, maybe no.  But I doubt that your personal definition would get much support.  Even in the Free Software community.

---

You might be confusing Open Source (or open source) with ["The Open Source Way"](http://www.theopensourceway.org/).  The latter is described as:

> "a way of thinking about how people collaborate within a community to achieve common goals and interests."

... but there is no "definitional requirement" that Open Source software be developed that way.  Or open source software either.

Comment: Why to keep 2 implementations i.e. Open JDK and Oracle's own version when both are being developed by Oracle itself and both have open source license?

Comment: The Open Source Initiative uses Initial Caps, see the comment to the question by @KevinKrumwiede. You are confusing Open Source with open source, sumit.

Comment: @sumitsachdeva - They don't both have an open source license.  The complete source code of Oracle's own version is not available unless you sign a license agreement with Oracle.  And the subset that is included in a JDK distribution is covered by the click-through agreement that you are supposed to agree to before downloading.

Comment: @DavidHammen - I'm not confusing them.  I am conflating them.  The problem is that "open source" is not a term with a single fixed definition.  It means different things to different people.  (Like the OP!)

Comment: @StephenC - My comment was directed at the OP rather than you. This answer, however, is a bit Open Source-centric (as opposed to open source). Adding to the confusion, there is dual-licensed software such as VMware and VirtualBox.

Comment: (The reason that my Answer is "Open Source" centric is that "Open Source" has a clear definition.  By contrast, open source (in lower case) has no agreed definition.  So obviously, questions that presuppose a common understanding of  "open source" means are unanswerable.)

Answer (score 4):

There are several questions and misunderstandings in your question. Let's address them one-by-one:

> Why do we call Java open source

I have no idea. Java is a programming language. A programming language is a set of abstract mathematical rules and restrictions. It doesn't really make sense to apply the ideas of "open source" to a language, because there is no "source".

It *would* make sense to call a language "open source" if the language specification could be freely forked and modified. But that is just non-sensical. The whole *point* of an infrastructure standard (and, yes, a language is both infrastructure and a standard) is that you can rely on it *not* changing.

> Open source software should be developed by different contributors in decentralized fashion.

That is not a part of what it means to be "open source". Open source is *purely* about the licensing terms of the software. Nothing else. OpenJDK is licensed under the GPL, and there are also other Java implementations, some of them forks or derivatives of OpenJDK, some independent clean-room developments that are released under an open-source license. Clearly, there are implementations of Java that are open-source (although the licensing restrictions on the "Java" *trademark* may make it impossible for some of those Java implementations to call themselves "Java").

I call what you are describing an "open project", which means that not only is the software released under an open source license, but also the project is developed in an open fashion, i.e. bug reports can be filed by anyone and are made publicly available, design discussions are held in the open, and with a way for the public to participate, contributions are welcome, and so on. That is, however, not part of the definition of open source.

Just something to think about: there is an ISO standard which covers some core parts of .NET and C♯. There are multiple open-source implementations of .NET (Mono, CoreCLR) and C♯ (Mono, Roslyn). Design discussions are held in the open, in GitHub issues. Bugs are tracked openly and publicly on GitHub. In fact, that's pretty much exactly like Java, even more so, because the Java Language Specification is owned by Oracle, whereas there is at least a subset of C♯ specified as an ISO standard. Yet, C♯ is typically characterized as closed-source whereas Java is typically characterized as open-source. IMO, this has much more to do with the image of Sun and Microsoft in the early 90s than with any actual facts.

Comment: "A programming language is a set of abstract mathematical rules and restrictions."  No, that's a language *specification*.  A programming language is a tool used by programmers, consisting of a compiler and a standard library.  As such, it absolutely does have source code.

Comment: I have written plenty of code in programming languages that didn't have an implementation. (Isn't university fun? Writing code that will never run, and that you can never test?) I have also written plenty of code in programming languages that didn't have a (formal) specification. There are plenty of programming languages which have only interpreters, no compilers (although they are getting rarer these days). What you are describing is a language *implementation*, not a language. Languages can exist separately from their implementations, e.g. Lisp wasn't intended to be implemented originally.

Comment: @sumitsachdeva: I don't understand your question. Yes, a programming language can be used to write a program. But that's it. If you want to *run* the program, you need a programming language *implementation*, either an interpreter to run it directly, or a compiler to translate it into a different language that you can then interpret.

Comment: A computer programming language implementation *is* a computer programming language, because if it's not implemented, you obviously can't program a computer in it.

Comment: @JörgWMittag : When we say java language specification we usually refer to Sun / Oracle's implementation. So, I am still confused about the difference between two.

Comment: @JörgWMittag is correct. A programming language is simply a [formal language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language) that is fed into a compiler or interpreter to provoke a computer into performing computations. A programming environment, its libraries, compiler suite, IDEs, and other associated software artifacts are not part of the language itself. The difference between a programming language and the programming tools it the difference between Programmers and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

> Open source software should be developed by different contributors in decentralized fashion.

Taken to its extreme, that's a recipe for chaos. Open source that has been forked, re-forked, and re-re-forked is rarely as successful as is open source that has some central organization guiding it and keeping it sane.

I'll look at what is arguably the most successful open source package ever, the Linux kernel. While there are lots and lots of Linux distributions, there is one and only one source for the Linux kernel itself is the Linux Kernel Organization, Inc., from [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org). Closer to the question, the Python language is open source. But the one and only place to get Python, officially, is from the Python Software Foundation at [python.org](https://www.python.org). One of the reasons for the successes of Linux and Python is that both have a strong centralized organization led by a beneficent dictator for life that reign in the chaos.

While Linux and Python are non-profit open source initiatives, there is plenty of open source that is maintained and coordinated by for-profit organizations. Java falls in this category. So do ParaView, VTK, and CMake (all from Kitware, Inc. at [kitware.com](http://www.kitware.com)), OpenVDB (from DreamWorks Animation via [openvdb.org](http://www.openvdb.org)), RenderMan (from Pixar Animation Studios via [renderman.pixar.com](https://renderman.pixar.com/view/renderman)), and many, many others. There are also numerous open source packages from [NASA](https://code.nasa.gov/#/) and from other government organizations. Releasing some of an organization's crown jewels to the world at large, for free, has come to make sense from a business perspective.

> Why do we call Java open source?

The term "open source" means different things to different people. To some, merely making a binary executable free to the public qualifies as "open source". Merely releasing binaries freely typically does not suffice to qualify as "open source" by most. The source code needs to be released as well. To others, "Open Source" means even more than that.

The source code for the standard Java libraries, Java compilers, and Java Virtual Machines are openly available in Mercurial repositories at [openjdk.java.net](http://openjdk.java.net). In this sense, Oracle's Java most certainly is "open source." Whether this qualifies as Open Source (note the use of Initial Caps) is a different matter and is subject to opinion.

Comment: There are lots and lots of forks of Linux. Almost every distribution maintains their own fork. Google maintains their own fork for Android, and another one for their cluster nodes. There are forks for devices without an MMU, there are forks with security enhancements whose policies Linus Torvalds doesn't like, there are forks which port Linux on-top of some microkernel (e.g. L4Linux), … Linux works, precisely because it is *not* centrally controlled. For a perspective what happens to a very similar project that *is* centrally controlled look at the BSD landscape, where pretty much every new …

Comment: … challenge where it isn't clear how to approach it leads to a schism with community fragmentation and lots of bad blood instead of just letting the different approaches co-exist peacefully and pick a winner over time, or pick the best parts of both (as has happened with linux-virt and Virtuozzo, for example).

Comment: @JörgWMittag Don't BSD advocates argue that the centralized approach leads to better, less bug-ridden code? I've seen this argued again and again by BSD advocates, that their approach leads to cleaner code with fewer vulnerabilities. I'm not in a position to have an opinion on this, not being a kernel or low-level developer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - Yes, organizations do maintain their own forks, but they also contribute mods back to and sync their forks with the Lunix Foundation code.